# batch script to delete and replace files in multiple locations

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

What I am looking to do is create a batch file to replace teh cert8.db file in a users application data folder as well as insert a line of text into one of the prefs.js file.  Normally this would be easy, the issue is that there is a good chance some of my users have multiple firefox profiles so I would like to have a script to to replace all cert8.db files in the firefox/profiles folder and insert 1 line of next into all prefs.js files in the firefox/profiles folder.

Can this be done?  I am willing to use vb if possible.

Comment: Task 1 is to locate the firefox profile storage location.  then locating the cert8.db files and replacing is easy, if they are not locked.  The prefs.js - do you merely want the text added to the end of the files, no matter what else is in them?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

profilesFolder  = "C:\Users"
firefoxProfiles = "AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"

For Each fldr In fso.GetFolder(profilesFolder)
  profilePath = fso.BuildPath(fldr.Path, firefoxAppdata)
  If fso.FolderExists(profilePath) Then
    For Each profile In fso.GetFolder(profilePath)
      certdb = fso.BuildPath(profile, "cert8.db")
      prefs  = fso.BuildPath(profile, "prefs.js")

      If fso.FileExists(certdb) Then
        'replace cert8.db
      End If

      If fso.FileExists(prefs) Then
        'modify prefs.js
      End If
    Next
  End If
Next
```

The code for replacing the DB file and modifying the preferences depends on where the replacement DB comes from and what you want to add or update in the preferences.

Comment: I inserted new code: Is under firefox profiles `newcertfile= "C:\firefox\cert8.db"` `If fso.FileExists(certdb)     Then objFSO.CopyFile "cert8.db","cert8.old"     objFSO.CopyFile newcertfile, OverwriteExisting `

Comment: Unless you set the working directory to the profile folder you need to use the full paths in `CopyFile`. Also I'd use `MoveFile` for renaming the old `cert8.db`, so you don't need to force overwriting of an existing file in the second step. Also, your second `CopyFile` has only the source path. You need a destination path as well.

Comment: I made the adjustment but it errors out with this: For Each fldr In fso.GetFolder(profilesFolder), i adjusted profilesFolder to `profilesFolder = "C:\users\%USERNAME%"     but its says the path does not exist

Comment: `FileSystemObject` doesn't expand environment variables, so you can't use stuff like `%USERNAME%` (or `%USERPROFILE%`) in a path without expanding the variables yourself (`var2 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings(var1)`).

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /D %%i IN (C:\Users\*.*) Do FOR /D %%j IN (%%i\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.*) Do (
    CALL :ReplaceDB "%%j\cert8.db"
    CALL :ChangeJS "%%j\prefs.js"
)

:ReplaceDB
IF NOT EXIST %1 GOTO :EOF
MOVE /Y %1 "%~1.old"
COPY C:\firefox\cert8.db %1
GOTO :EOF

:ChangeJS
IF NOT EXIST %1 GOTO :EOF
ECHO user_pref("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", "pac.pe.lan/pac/proxy.pac") >> %1
GOTO :EOF
```

EDIT: Added second `FOR` to search profiles.
EDIT: Added code for replacing DB and appending line to JS.

Comment: these 2 files would actually be in profiles\somethingrandom\cert8.db and perfs.js I would be able to do something like "%%i\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\\*\cert8.db"?

Comment: I did this however I am the files are being copied to C:\, how can have have them be in the (%%i\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.*) ?
:ReplaceDB</br>
IF NOT EXIST %1 GOTO :EOF</br>
REM Replace DB in %1 here!</br>
rename cert8.db cert8.db.old</br>
Copy C:\firefox\cert8.db cert8.db</br>
GOTO :EOF</br>
:ChangeJS</br>
IF NOT EXIST %1 GOTO :EOF</br>
REM Change JS in %1 here!</br>
set str1=%~1 </br>
set str1=%str1:user_pref</br>("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", "http://pac.pe.lan/pac/proxy.pac");</br></br>
GOTO :EOF pro